# download data is faster but ping speed is slower why?

Tags: vps, vultr

I am looking for the [vultr](https://www.vultr.com/faq/#downloadspeedtests) or [digitalocean](http://speedtest-sgp1.digitalocean.com/) to host my website. 
however, when I ping it I find something confuse me:
ping Singapore Vultr 
[image]
ping Tokyo Vultr 
[image]
it seems Singapore Vultr  is faster than Tokyo.But,when I download the data from Singapore and Tokyo that Tokyo is much faster than Singapore
[image]

just wondering why?

does that mean bandwidth transfer Tokyo is bigger than Singapore?

thanks

Comment: ping measures latency, not throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a difference in bandwidth and latency of both servers. The latency of the Singapore server is better than the Tokyo vultr server but the bandwidth of Tokyo Vultr server is better than the Singapore server.
If you need to know the difference between bandwidth and latency you can visit [bandwidth-vs-latency](https://www.highspeedinternet.com/resources/bandwidth-vs-latency-what-is-the-difference)